# Does the line integral in a vector field being 0 imply the curl of the field is 0?

Tags: vector-analysis

I understand that the curl of a vector field being 0 implies that line integrals along closed curves in the field are 0. But is the opposite true? I'm having difficulty finding anything definitive on this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is the set simply connected?

Comment: For the opposite, do you mean arbitrary closed curve or a given closed curve?

Comment: Along a simply closed curve. I'm just wondering in general, is it possible to have a closed curve in a vector field along which the line integral is 0, even if the curl is not 0?

Comment: Yes, a simply connected curve (which I believe means no holes in the middle?) that terminology is new to me sorry.

Comment: Simply connected curve does nor exist. To ensure that the curl is zero you have to take into accont ALL closed curves in a certain set, all of them being zero. Then you can say something about the curl if the set is "nice".

Comment: The integral can be $0$ along a given curve, whereas the curl of the field is not.